# SQLAlchemy hybrid expression that accesses another hybrid expression not working as intended

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following hybrid expression for the Investments class:

```
class Investments(BaseModel):
    
    @ invested_capital.expression
    def invested_capital(cls):
        return (
            select(func.sum(InvestmentHistory.capital_value)).
            where(InvestmentHistory.investment_fk == cls.id, or_(InvestmentHistory.capital_movement_type == "SUBSCRIBED_CAPITAL", InvestmentHistory.capital_movement_type == "CAPITAL_BOOST")).
            label('invested_capital')
        )

    @participation_percentage.expression
    def participation_percentage(cls):
        return (
            select(cls.invested_capital * 100 / Opportunities.invested_amount).
            where(Opportunities.id == cls.opportunity_fk, cls.id == Investments.id).
            label('participation_percentage')
        )
```

Basically the invested capital is a sum of "Investment History" records that relate to the table "Investments" in the foreign key 'investment_fk'.
That value is being correctly calculated, and it represents how much an investor has invested in a given opportunity. For this example lets say that that an investor X has invested 100€ in the Opportunity Y - which has an invested_amount of 10.000€.

Now lets say we want to calculate what's the percentage that investor X holds in the opportunity Y. The intended value is 1 (%) however, using the participation_percentage expression, it returns millions - which is the sum of all invested capital for any opportunity divided by invested_amount for the opportunity Y.
How come when accessing Investments.invested_capital in a query we get the correct invested value, but if we query via cls.invested_capital in participation_percentage expression it does not seem to the relate to this specific record

I have tried to add 'cls.id == Investments.id' hoping it would help to disambiguate which record I was referring to. Is it doing anything at all?

Thanks